# how to make yaxis ticks as hyperlink in flot graphs

Tags: flot

I am creating a line graph with flot library and in y-axis all my ticks are abbreviation and i want to make all my ticks as hyperlink so on open of a page they get more details about abb.

Here is my code to make y-axis:

```
  var ranks = Context.CreateDataContext().Ranks.OrderBy(c => c.RankID);
        var yaxis = new StringBuilder(" { yaxis : {ticks:[");
        foreach (var item in ranks)
        {
            if (item.RankID == 0)
                   yaxis.AppendFormat(@"[{0},'{1}'],", item.RankID, "None");
                if (item.RankID == 1)
                    yaxis.AppendFormat(@"[{0},'{1}'],", item.RankID, "AMB");
                if (item.RankID == 2)
                    yaxis.AppendFormat(@"[{0},'{1}'],", item.RankID, "BA");
                if (item.RankID == 3)
                    yaxis.AppendFormat(@"[{0},'{1}'],", item.RankID, "SA");
                if (item.RankID == 4)
                    yaxis.AppendFormat(@"[{0},'{1}'],", item.RankID, "GA");
                if (item.RankID == 5)
                    yaxis.AppendFormat(@"[{0},'{1}'],", item.RankID, "PA");
                if (item.RankID == 6)
                    yaxis.AppendFormat(@"[{0},'{1}'],", item.RankID, "RA");
                if (item.RankID == 7)
                    yaxis.AppendFormat(@"[{0},'{1}'],", item.RankID, "EA");
                if (item.RankID == 8)
                    yaxis.AppendFormat(@"[{0},'{1}'],", item.RankID, "DA");
                if (item.RankID == 9)
                    yaxis.AppendFormat(@"[{0},'{1}'],", item.RankID, "DDA");
                if (item.RankID == 10)
                    yaxis.AppendFormat(@"[{0},'{1}'],", item.RankID, "TDA");
                if (item.RankID == 11)
                    yaxis.AppendFormat(@"[{0},'{1}'],", item.RankID, "PDA");
                if (item.RankID == 12)
                    yaxis.AppendFormat(@"[{0},'{1}'],", item.RankID, "CDA");
        }
        yaxis.Append("]}}");
```

and i want to make "AMB","BA","SA","GA"....all as links or tooltip..

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You can try the `tickFormatter` option to customize the tick labels (see the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) for more details). A starting point:

```
function formatter(val, axis) {
    return '<span title="' + getFullNameForAbbreviation(val) + '">' + val + '</span>';
}
```

You will have to add the function to get the full names from the abbreviations.

Comment: Here's a fiddle implementng @Raidri's suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/CaMFz/, note that inorder to make the hyperlinks clickable, I had to up their `z-index` to get them ontop of the canvas.

Comment: It's tricky, because the overlay canvas is what's covering them up, and it should (though usually not strictly necessary) have a higher z-index.  The nicest solution is to use the pointer-events property, but I don't think it's supported in IE or Opera yet.  Might be worth doing anyway, to at least help some people out.  Uglier solution would be to proxy the event.